# cLion & cMake not debugning/printing an error

Tags: c++, debugging, cmake, clion

I have a weird issue that I just learned about. If I run this code in Visual Studio I get output that is NULL/error. But when I run in cLion I just get app crash and no feedback.

VS error :

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
this was nullptr.
```

Here is my config:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class testNothing {
public:
    testNothing *test;
    void donothing() { cout << test << endl; };
};

int main()
{
    testNothing *hey = nullptr;

    hey->donothing();

    return 1;
};
```

CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(tests)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: Not sure why you tagged this as `debugging` when you don't appear to have tried any...? The program printing a runtime error is not "debugging"; you need to invoke that yourself. SO is not a debugging service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To receive feedback, you may run your project in 'Debug' mode.

You may go to Run > Debug from menu bar, or simply press the 'bug' icon on the top left corner to enter debug mode.

Output in debug mode : `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`.

You'll also get complete interactive stack trace of the same.

Comment: Given how many questions are posted where the OP didn't try debugging, I think it's better just to write a comment linking them to a catch-all tutorial for debugging, rather than posting an answer. While this might explain how they can find the answer, it's not an answer in and of itself.

Comment: Thanks for the info about debug. I Only used python before and the "run" function of pycharm/cline. Did not realize that there is a debug option as I assumed that that was happening when I run it normally. Like in python. Bit weird that its not 1 and the same action tho... ?

Comment: @Dariusz It's not meant to be same action. Runtime errors are meant to be shown at "runtime". :) I can understand missing the 'debug' option.

If this answers your question, kindly mark it as accepted!